K8s Uvicorn server shuts down after sending a large file response
My application utilizes a uvicorn server which does some heavy computation and sends the results back. I decided not to use gunicorn since I don't expect to receive multiple concurrent requests.
However, after processing larger files (around 20 MB), the server takes some time to process the results and sends it back to the client. However, immediately after sending the response, the pod restarts. The logs from the pods don't hint at an issue.
TRACE:    10.1.0.169:37460 - ASGI [27] Send {'type': 'http.response.body', 'body': '<181688276 bytes>'}
TRACE:    10.1.0.169:37460 - ASGI [27] Completed
TRACE:    10.1.0.169:59054 - ASGI [28] Started scope={'type': 'http', 'asgi': {'version': '3.0', 'spec_version': '2.4'}, 'http_version': '1.1', 'server': ('10.1.0.200', 8082), 'client': ('10.1.0.169', 59054), 'scheme': 'https', 'method': 'GET', 'root_path': '', 'path': '/api/api/analytics', 'raw_path': b'/api/api/analytics', 'query_string': b'', 'headers': '<...>', 'state': {}}
TRACE:    10.1.0.169:59054 - ASGI [28] Send {'type': 'http.response.start', 'status': 200, 'headers': '<...>'}
INFO:     10.1.0.169:59054 - "GET /api/api/analytics HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
TRACE:    10.1.0.169:59054 - ASGI [28] Send {'type': 'http.response.body', 'body': '<189 bytes>'}
TRACE:    10.1.0.169:59054 - ASGI [28] Completed
TRACE:    10.1.0.1:35148 - HTTP connection made
TRACE:    10.1.0.1:35148 - ASGI [29] Started scope={'type': 'http', 'asgi': {'version': '3.0', 'spec_version': '2.4'}, 'http_version': '1.1', 'server': ('10.1.0.200', 8082), 'client': ('10.1.0.1', 35148), 'scheme': 'https', 'method': 'GET', 'root_path': '', 'path': '/docs', 'raw_path': b'/docs', 'query_string': b'', 'headers': '<...>', 'state': {}}
TRACE:    10.1.0.1:35148 - ASGI [29] Send {'type': 'http.response.start', 'status': 200, 'headers': '<...>'}
INFO:     10.1.0.1:35148 - "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
TRACE:    10.1.0.1:35148 - ASGI [29] Send {'type': 'http.response.body', 'body': '<1960 bytes>'}
TRACE:    10.1.0.1:35148 - ASGI [29] Completed
TRACE:    10.1.0.1:35148 - HTTP connection lost
INFO:     Started server process [7]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
TRACE:    ASGI [1] Started scope={'type': 'lifespan', 'asgi': {'version': '3.0', 'spec_version': '2.0'}, 'state': {}}
TRACE:    ASGI [1] Receive {'type': 'lifespan.startup'}
TRACE:    ASGI [1] Send {'type': 'lifespan.startup.complete'}
INFO:     Application startup complete.

Increase the timeouts for the nginx proxy, increasing the pod resources don't seem to help. The pod always restarts. Is there any way to fix this issue?
